# Jquery checkbox checked when page loads

Tags: jquery, checkbox, pageload

The script is working fine however I am wondering if there is a way to avoid the repetition in the code (DRY method).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/t01a9cxL/)

JS code:

```
// Checkbox checked and input disbaled when page loads

$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);

if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked') == true) {
    $('#textInput').prop('disabled', true);
}


// Enable-Disable text input when checkbox is checked or unchecked

$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#textInput').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#textInput').val('').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just set the textbox as disabled in the html?
You only care about it being enabled after the user has unchecked the checkbox :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you can't set the attributes by default in `HTML`:

```
// Checkbox checked and input disbaled when page loads
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);

// Enable-Disable text input when checkbox is checked or unchecked
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var value = this.checked ? $('#textInput').val() : '';
    $('#textInput').prop('disabled', this.checked).val(value);
}).trigger('change');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/t01a9cxL/1/

Answer (score 3):

If every time the page is loaded you want the check box to be checked and the text box to be disabled it's better to do it in HTML

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked="true" />
<input type="text" id="textInput" disabled=""/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Enable-Disable text input when checkbox is checked or unchecked

$('#checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#textInput').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#textInput').val('').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate your logic into a reusable function:

```
function checkboxStatus() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#textInput').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#textInput').val('').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

// Checkbox checked and input disbaled when page loads
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
checkboxStatus();

// Enable-Disable text input when checkbox is checked or unchecked
$('#checkbox').change(checkboxStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple make it as easy jquery in have many ways to done**

```
$('#checkbox').prop( 'checked', true ); // when intially checked
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
     $('#textInput').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
     if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#textInput').val('')
     }
}).change(); //intially trigger the event change
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t01a9cxL/3/)

Comment: @Tushar I Misunderstood Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same result with less code as follows:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/t01a9cxL/2/)

```
// Checkbox checked and input disbaled when page loads
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#textInput').prop('disabled', true);

// Enable-Disable text input when checkbox is checked or unchecked
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked') == true;
    $('#textInput').prop('disabled', checked);
});
```